# SQL Trigger to copy value from Table A - Column A to Table B - Column A IF Value is unique in Table B

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have two tables:

Table A with multiple columns and Table B with two columns.

What I want to do after inserting a new row in to Table A is:

1. Check to see if the value that was inserted in to **Table A - Column C** is already in **Table B**
2. If the value is **not** in **Table B** insert the data from **Table A - Column C** in to **Table B - Column B** and **set Table B - Column C to a value of 1**
3. If the value in **Table A - Column C** is already present in **Table B**, then locate the ROW and **increment the value in Table B - Column C by 1**

Hope someone can help as I'm unable to find a solution to this.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: You should generally avoid *storing* information that you can easily calculate. The query `SELECT ColumnC,COUNT(*) FROM TableA GROUP BY ColumnC` will always give you the correct count of the number of rows in `TableA` with each distinct `ColumnC` value.

Comment: The indexed view would solve the problem, although I need to have the ability to remove one of the unique rows from Table B, but keep all the data in Table A. To explain it a little clearer, Table A holds all the data received from a form which contains contact details.  Table B holds a list of contact details built from Table A and needs to only have unique values, so basically no duplication of an email address for instance as the table will be used to send bulk communications and if an email address was present multiple times they would receive the communication multiple times. On top of

Comment: that if the client wants their email address for instance removed from the list I need to be able to delete it from Table B.

Comment: @user2969479 - given that delete scenario, what happens if that same email address is subsequently added back in as a new row in Table A - should they then start to receive emails again, despite their stated preference against?

Answer (score 0):

The following is Oracle syntax, so someone will need to translate this into MYSQL.
The work done in a trigger should always be kept to a minimum, so the other writers
are correct when they say you may want to find a different way of doing this.

I found your references to columns confusing, so I am substituting FK and PK for
the column names.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tablea
   AFTER INSERT OR DELETE
   ON tablea
   REFERENCING NEW AS new OLD AS old
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

   IF INSERTING
   THEN

      UPDATE tableb
         SET cnt   = cnt + 1
       WHERE fk = :new.pk;

      IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0
      THEN

         INSERT INTO tableb (
                        fk, cnt
                     )
              VALUES (:new.pk, 1);

      END IF;

   END IF;

   IF DELETING
   THEN

      UPDATE tableb
         SET cnt   = cnt - 1
       WHERE fk = :old.pk;

   END IF;

END;
```